# Using switch in recyclerview with databinding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, data-binding

Here is what I am trying to do:

1. When the switch is toggled in the recyclerview
2. Update the item (alarm) which was toggled to the switch state (true or false) using my viewModel from the fragment (Passing the ID of the clicked item (alarm) to my fragment and update its status from the switch)

I, personally dont fancy the idea of having a reference of the viewModel in my adapter..but is that the way out..:(?

I am having difficulty implementing this with databinding.

**recycler_view_item.xml**

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="alarm"
        type="com.package.appname.Alarm" />

    <variable
        name="fragment"
        type="com.package.appname.ui.fragments.AlarmFragment" />

        .................
       <com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:checked="@{alarm.status}"
            android:onCheckedChanged="@{(button, bool)-> 
            fragment.updateAlarmStatus(bool)}"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/rcv_lyt_margin_spacing"/>

</data>
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter.kt**

```
class AlarmAdapter(private val onClickListener: OnAlarmClickListener) : ListAdapter<Alarm, AlarmAdapter.AlarmViewHolder>(AlarmDiffCallback()) {

class AlarmViewHolder private constructor(private val binding: 
RcvLytAlarmsBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){

    fun bind(alarm: Alarm?){
        binding.alarm = alarm
        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }
}
```

**AlarmFragment.kt**

```
fun updateAlarmStatus(status: Boolean){
    //Here I want to use my viewmodel to update the selected alarm like 
    vieModel.updateAlarmStatus(alarmClicked)
    Timber.d(status.toString()) <--- This code is not been called, IDK why
}
```